# Area of the Trajectory of a Rotating Square

Tags: calculus, area, rotations

**The Question**
We have a square with vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ that is rotating as in the link below. What is the area of the trajectory the it traces out? [Here's the link. Use the slider for $s$ to show the animation.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jsfxoohroj)
I have no idea how to start and would appreciate any type of answer.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
The problem I'm having is that when $s$ is around $\frac{3}{4}$, there's this region of the square that is not included in the heart-like shape, as it is not a convex set. The other parts are very easy so as long as we can find the area of that region, the problem is solved.

Comment: Do you know integration (esp given that you tagged with calculus)? You've found the formula for the curves already, so just need to find the area under the curve. $\quad$ IE What is $ \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2 } + x \, dx$?

Comment: The problem I'm encountering is that there's this place where the square "pokes out" which I have no idea how to find the area of which.

Comment: I think I see the problematic region you mean (near the point $(1,1)$). It might help get the right kind of answer if you could point out that region more explicitly in the text of the question.

Comment: Calculate the area in the y direction by means of integration., multiply by 2 and subtract the square area.

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iiemxxdcxe) is a graph that correctly shows the region swept out by the square, including the part near $(1,1)$.

Comment: @MathIsFun Please check my updated solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the unrotated square has the following vertices: $A (0,0), B = (0, 1), C = (1,1), D (1, 0)$, then consider a rotation of the square by an angle $t$ counter clockwise.  In this case the new vertices will be at

$A = (\sin t, 0) , B = (0, \cos t) $

$C = B + (1)(\cos t, \sin t ) = (\cos t , \cos t + \sin t ) $

$ D = A + (1) ( \cos t, \sin t ) = (\sin t + \cos t , \sin t ) $

In addition to the trajectories of $C$ and $D$, we need to find the envelope of the straight line segment that connects $C$ to $D$.  The equation of this segment as a function of $t$ is

$ \dfrac{y - (\cos t + \sin t)}{x - \cos t } = - \dfrac{\cos t }{\sin t} $

Therefore,

$ \sin t (y - (\cos t + \sin t) ) + \cos t (x - \cos t ) = 0 \hspace{5pt} (1)$

Differentiating this equation with respect to $t$, gives us

$ \cos t (y - (\cos t + \sin t) ) + \sin t ( - (- \sin t + \cos t ) ) - \sin t (x - \cos t ) + \cos t ( \sin t ) = 0 $

So that

$ \cos t (y - (\cos t + \sin t) ) - \sin t (x - \cos t ) = - \sin^2 t \hspace{5pt}(2) $

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain

$ x - \cos t =  \sin^3 t $

$ y - (\cos t + \sin t) = - \cos t \sin^2 t = - \cos t (1 - \cos^2 t)$

So that,

$ x = \cos t + \sin^3 t $

$ y = \sin t + \cos^3 t $

Both the trajectories of $C$ and $D$ are plotted in black in the figure below, while the envelope is plotted in red.

[image]

The total area enclosed is the area within the black curve plus the area within the red curve.  The overlap is negligible.

To find the total area bounded by the curve that $C$ and $D$ traces, we have to combine the three curves and apply the following formula

$ \text{Area} = \dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle \int x(t) y'(t) - x'(t) y(t) dt $

For the $D$ curve, we have

$ x = \sin t + \cos t $

$ y = \sin t $

So,

$ x' = \cos t - \sin t $

$ y' = \cos t $

Therefore, the integrand is

$ x y' - y x' = (\sin t + \cos t ) (\cos t ) - (\sin t) (\cos t - \sin t ) = 1 $

While for the $E$ curve we have

$ x = \cos s + \sin^3 s $

$ y = \sin s + \cos^3 s $

So,

$ x' = - \sin s + 3 \sin^2 s \cos s $

$ y' = \cos s - 3 \cos^2 s \sin s $

It can be easily shown that the integrand will be

$ x y' - y x' = \dfrac{5}{8} - \sin(2 s) + \dfrac{3}{8} \cos(4 s) $

Therefore, the area is given by

$ \text{Area} = (2)(\frac{1}{2})\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} 1  \ d t + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi / 2 } \left(\dfrac{5}{8} - \sin(2 s) + \dfrac{3}{8} \cos(4 s) \right)  \ d s $

The above integral is straight forward to evaluate and the result is

$ \text{Area} = 1.579922 $

Now, if we want to be more precise, we have to find the intersection points between the trajectory of $D$ and the envelope (the lower right blue dot), the other intersection (the upper left dot) is symmetrical with respect to the line $y = x$.  To find the intersection point, we recall that $D$ is given by

$ C = ( \sin t + \cos t , \sin t ) $

while the envelope is

$E = ( \cos s + \sin^3 s , \sin s + \cos^3 s ) $

Using Newton-Raphson multivariate root finding method, we find that the two curves intersect at

$ t = 1.39094282700263$

$ s = 1.10714871778309$

(This gives the precise intersection lower right intersection point close the extreme point marked in blue where the $E$ curve flips direction)

The area integral changes now to

$ \text{Area} = (2)(\frac{1}{2})\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1.390942827} 1  \ d t + (2) \frac{1}{2} \int_{1.1071487178}^{\pi / 4 } \left(\dfrac{5}{8} - \sin(2 s) + \dfrac{3}{8} \cos(4 s) \right)  \ d s $

The precise value of the area as computed by this integral is

$ \text{Area} = 1.5798487305 $

The difference in the two calculations is the area of the overlap between black region and the red region and this is $\approx 0.00007326$

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: @DavidK I have plotted the traced curve, and it does not intersect the square, so I don't know what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @DavidK I see now what you mean.  I have to review my calculations.

Comment: This addresses all my comments and then some. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!

We can show the trajectories like this:

[image]

Now, it *really* looks like the area of $I$ equals the area of $II$. How can we prove that, though?

Well, I find it easier to prove visually, and it has to do with some symmetry.

First off: $A$ stays on the Y-axis and $D$ on the X-axis when we rotate the square *counterclockwise*. Furthermore, that moves $B$ to $(0,1)$ via the $\color{green}{green}$ path.

When we rotate the previous image, we get this:
[image]

...and we can mirror it to get **this.**

[image]

Let's adjust the coordinates so that $C(0,1)$ and $D(0,0)$. $C$ stays on the Y-axis and $D$ on the X-axis as we rotate the square *counterclockwise*. This moves $B$ to $(0,1)$ via the $\color{purple}{purple}$ path.

Notice anything? **It's the exact same thing!** The square and rotation stays the same. This means the $\color{purple}{purple}$ and $\color{green}{green}$ paths are the same.

So, the area of $I$ equals the area of $II$. Now we can simplify like this:
$$Area=[I]+[II]+[III]$$
$$Area=2[I]+1$$

...and we can proceed with integration.

Comment: OP is having some difficulty describing the region whose area is to be computed. It's more than just regions $I$, $II$, and $III$.

Comment: @DavidK ohh, I see. You mean the path crossed by the line $(1,0)-(1,1)$ adds some more area, am I right? Didn't realize that also counts, the problem gets more interesting then 

Comment: Yes, I think that's what OP wants. And yes, the problem gets much more interesting that way.